# OutlinedBox TextInputLayout not showing Android

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I have an issue that OutlinedBox of my TextInputLayout not showing.
Here is my xml lines :

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/formnomor"
            style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:theme="@style/appz">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/no"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nr"
                android:hint="Number"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:maxLength="16"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And for the style and theme :

```
    <style name="TextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">#fff</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeWidth">1dp</item>
    </style>
```

```
<style name="appz" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="boxBackgroundMode">outline</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

For now, I use `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'` dependencies, but I have tried many dependencies on it but still not working..

Comment: Considering that all of your `colorControl` colors are white, and your `boxStrokeColor` is white, and your theme inherits from a `.Light` theme... is the problem just that it's really hard to see white on white?

Comment: @BenP. The problem is.. the `OutlinedBox` didn't showing to the interface, I just see the underline, and the `colorControl` just change the underline color

Comment: Try to use the version 1.2.1

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti still the same, problem still exists with other dependencies